# I lost my computer, inside my hive wallet , I do have my adress and password can I recover my bitcoins?

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery, hive

Is it possible to login from other wallet with adress and password to get back my btc?

Comment: Platform? Details? We need much more info. What about your mnemonic?

Comment: Please add additional information. As it stands, we don't have enough information to know what your problem is.

Answer (score 2):

The address is useless, the password insufficient. You need to have a **backup** of your wallet, or know the **mnemonics** for the seed. Otherwise you can't recover your coins.